# Having trouble with the aiy-python-wheels on Raspberry Pi 3. How do I resolve incompatible glibc issue?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, grpc, glibc, google-authentication

I've gotten my hands on a AIY voice kit v1 and am stuck with the assistant_grpc_demo.py with it failing at an import statement with the grpc. I should have everything installed already, yet google.auth.transport can't seem to find it. I am using a pi 3 A+. Below is the terminal commands I used and their outputs.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat testinput.py 
import google.auth.transport.grpc
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 testinput.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 30, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc import _compression
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testinput.py", line 1, in <module>
    import google.auth.transport.grpc
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 37, in <module>
    caught_exc,
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
ImportError: gRPC is not installed, please install the grpcio package to use the gRPC transport.
```

*Maybe the glibc part is the problem. Not sure how to resolve that as I already have libc6 2.28. Is there a way to get the aiy-python-wheels to work with my set-up or a previous version. Already tried flashing a pre-built official image built on 4-13-2018 with everything set up, though it failed to boot. Trying to download all packages manually. assistant_library_with_button.sh works though.

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure how to resolve that as I already have libc6 2.28

The error message says: `.../site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so` *requires* `GLIBC_2.33`.

Your `libc6` is *too old* for that gRPC package to work -- it was compiled on a newer system.

You must either:

- get a different gRPC package -- one compiled on and suitable for running on a GLIBC-2.28 (or earlier) based system, or
- get a different GLIBC package (2.33 or later).